# Drupal 7 - override / disable admin node and implement a custom one

Tags: drupal, overriding, drupal-7, admin

i would like to know how to override/disable an admin node and implement a custom one.

What i want to do is to make a custom node/add/page with different layout and tools and css in order to allow not so technical users to create content with custom layout an content using some sort of drag and drop interface.

This interface is already working, all i need is to know how to convert it into the new node/add/page.

Thanks in advance and forgive may bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have this working you can override the **node/add/page** path by providing an alias to your custom path. Simply visit **admin/config/search/path/add**.

Comment: and thanks for your answer, it is technically correct but that would force me to make the whole node form zero, what i want is to use the same node/add/page and deactivate some elements and add a few ones (the interface) in order to generate 'content' via this interface and use the built in functionality to save it. If this can't be done, your answer above is an interesting way, in that case can you tell me how to implement a 'clone' of the original node/add/page with all the functionality.